# Very slow execution of Matlab code under ubuntu

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, sparse-matrix, symbolic-math

I was using MATLAB 2012a under windows 7 and I was executing some intense code, and I mean by intense in terms of memory usage and processing time, however, the code was working fine on Windows. Now, I changed my OS to ubuntu 12.04 and I installed Matlab 2013a. The amount of memory used is considerably less than the way it was in Windows, but the time taken by matlab to execute the same code is extremely high-really high.

I need to mention that my code contain nothing that may take such huge time except a statement of sparse with symbolic substitution as one of the arguments as follows

```
K=zeros(Np,Np);

for i=1:ord
K=K+sparse(t(1:ord,:),repmat(t(i,:),ord,1),double(subs(Kv(:,i),Arg(Kv,1,1,6),Arg(Kv,1,2,6))),Np,Np);
end
```

Note: that Kv is a symbolic matrix and Arg is a function to provide OLD and NEW and it depends on a number of global variables.

I have the feeling that I missed to add something to ubuntu that might help accelerate the execution of the Matlab codes.
Any ideas ?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/154837/how-to-make-the-execution-of-a-matlab-program-faster

Comment: Regarding the optimization of the code ... I need to emphazise that I just need it to run (at least) the same way it did under windows. Right now I am suffering from a real delay compared to the time taken under windows. I am using only 20% of the RAM and swap is showing 0% ... so we can exclude the waste of time due to HD access time.

Comment: I need also to say ... I am using a light version of the code.. which means .. it should respond somehow faster than the usual run.

Comment: No idea, but you might try breaking up that long line into a series a statements to see if any one or more is largely responsible for the slowdown. Also, I think you can replace `K=zeros(Np,Np);` with `K=sparse(Np,Np);`.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem at windows, but I believe the solution is same on Ubuntu LTS. 
So, if you increase the Java Heap Memory of Matlab, the Matlab will consume more memory from your system but it will be faster.

To do that go to:
File->preferences->General->Java Heap Memory and increase to the maximum. 
The default value is 128, that is too little.

Comment: The other thing I can think is to split your for as you said and use parallel loop `parfor`

Comment: I don't think the problem is within the code ... the code worked fine under windows with the same hardware....the problem appeared due to the change of the OS to Ubuntu or the change of Matlab 2012 to Matlab 2013... the question is what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

If heap memory limit doesn't fix the issue, then try increasing matlab process.

First start matlab, then do

```
ps aux|grep MATLAB
```

In my case the result is:

```
comtom    9769 28.2 19.8 4360632 761808 tty2   S<l+ 14:00   1:50 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB -desktop
```

Look at first number (PID). Then use it with command renice to change process  priority:

```
renice -3 -p 9769
```

That's it. The GUI is very slow because it's built against outdated Xorg libs. So changing priority helps, you may notice some gnome effect's tear, but matlab's interface will work a lot better.